# Netezza substr function- how do i remove set number of chars from the right

Tags: substring, netezza

i am querying netezza server. i have a string in one of the column and i want to remove the last character in the string. The string is not a fixed length one and the last character is not constant either.

how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is `s`, then you can use `substr(s,0,length(s)-1)`

Just replace `s` with whatever you're querying.